# priority oriented TODO list manager

Tags: linux, offline, time-management, reminders

priority oriented TODO list manager

Comment: Like [AbstractSpoon ToDoList](http://www.abstractspoon.com/), just for Linux :-( Sorry, don't know. Can you run it in Wine or so?

Comment: @Thomas - for now I am testing it on windows - and it seems to be quite promising. I will check whatever it works fine in WIne.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Priority Oriented TODO list manager

I highly recommend [emacs orgmode](http://orgmode.org/)

[image: Orgmode Demo jpg]

Reasons:

- [You can prioritize your items](http://orgmode.org/manual/Priorities.html)
- [Recurring tasks](http://orgmode.org/manual/Repeated-tasks.html)
- open source (part of gnu emacs, included by default in modern releases!)
- Linux (and other OS's)
- local files (you can place under version control)
- I did get emacs running on my Android tablet (but it's not super easy)

It's really easy to get started, just open a file in emacs with `.org` as a suffix, and [breeze through a tutorial](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/orgtutorial_dto.html).

Comment: I am not marking it as answered for now as I still have to test it, but it is really promising. BTW, for people new to Emacs http://superuser.com/questions/253340/in-emacs-what-does-m-key-mean is likely to be useful.